# Remove and get text, from comma separated string if it has # as prefix in java?

Tags: java, string

I have a string in java as

**Input**

```
String str = "1,2,3,11,#5,#7,9";
```

**Output Desired**

```
String result = "1,2,3,11,9";
// And 5,7 with special character # in separate Array-list
//List<String> list = ["5","7"];
```

**Note**: This special character **#** is dynamic, it may or may not be present in string.

I know how to remove # using str.replaceAll("#", "");, but how to get 5 and 7 in a separate list.

Comment: Could you please share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: So your desired result consists of **two lists**? One for the numbers with a leading symbol and another one for the numbers without? Is that correct?

Comment: No, the number without special character in a string. And number with # (special character) as prefix in arraylist.

Comment: Please show us your effort... You are likely to get help soon after that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String str = "1,2,3,11,#5,#7,9";
    List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
    List<Integer> normalNumbers = parts.stream().filter(i -> !i.startsWith("#")).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(
            Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> specialNumbers = parts.stream().filter(i -> i.startsWith("#")).map(i -> Integer.valueOf(i.substring(1))).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(normalNumbers);
    System.out.println(specialNumbers);
```

Comment: @John ... interesting that you changed your mind on what you're looking for: **Output Desired** `String result = "1,2,3,11,9";` together with `// And 5,7 with special character # in separate Array-list` `//List<String> list = ["5","7"];` – this (accepted) answer doesn't immediately produce what you stated as the expected result in your question ;)

Comment: It was better, and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`String` in Java has a method called `split()`. You could easily use this to get all Integers with & without the `prefix #`

```
        String str = "1,2,3,11,#5,#7,9";
        
        List<Integer> res = Arrays.asList(str.split(",")).stream().map(ch->{
            if(!ch.startsWith("#")){
                return Integer.parseInt(ch);
            }else {
                return null;
            }
        }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: Prints `[1, 2, 3, 11, 9]` (which is more or less what OP wants `String result = "1,2,3,11,9";`) but doesn't deliver on OP's second result expectation: `// And 5,7 with special character # in separate Array-list` `//List<String> list = ["5","7"];`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "1,2,3,11,#5,#7,9";
List<String> s = Arrays.asList(str.split(",")).stream().filter(a->a.startsWith("#")).map(a->a.replace("#", "")).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(s);  //Output [5, 7]
str = Arrays.asList(str.split(",")).stream().filter(a->!a.startsWith("#")).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(str); //Output 1,2,3,11,9
```

Comment: It gives exception as
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed. But I am running your code in a main function to test.

Answer (score 0):

**1. You could try String.split(),**

```
String[] tokens = str.split(",");
```

**2. Create 2 new String Array-List,**

```
ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**3. Then loop thru the tokens, checking each token, then push,**

```
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
{
    if(tokens[i].charAt(0) == '#')
        num.add(String.valueOf(tokens[i].charAt(1)));
    else
        result.add(tokens[i]);
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: Replace `num.add(String.valueOf(tokens[i].charAt(1)));` with `num.add(tokens[i].substring(1));`. `substring()` returns a String and will also work for numbers which are not a single digit, e.g. 42.